# Custom menu walker: how can i check first item

Tags: sub-menu, walker

I need to output different html code only for the first item of my submenus.
How can I check in start_el() function if current item is first or not?

Example:

```
Menu voice 1
-- Sub 1
-- Sub 2
-- Sub 3
Menu voice 2
Menu voice 3
Menu voice 4
```

I would know when I'm in Sub1

**UPDATE - I've solved using Static Var:**

```
class my_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    static $count=0;
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {         
        global $wp_query;

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';

        if ($depth==0) self::$count=0;  // reset var when we are in first level


        if ($depth==1 && self::$count==1) {  // if we are in submenu and items count is 1...

            //your custom code              

        }

        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

        self::$count++;  // increase counter
    }


}
```

Comment: There is a variable $depth, 0 is the parent, 1 is one level down and so forth.

Comment: Yes I know, but itsn't the problem. I don't want to know the dept of menu, but when I'm on the first item of submenu.

For example I want to know when I'm on Sub1 in the following menu:

Main 1 > Sub1 | Sub2 | Sub3 | Sub4

Comment: I don't think there is an elegant way to do this other than add a counter and reset the counter on every parent depth.  So if ( $depth = 1 && $counter = 0 ) { // do something }

Comment: mmm it seems not so easy... which is the right way to declare var?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I spent 4 hours trying to do this yesterday, I didn't know about the `self` bit.

Comment: I need to do the exact opposite here, which is IMPOSSIBLE.  I need to be able to determine if a menu item is the LAST menu item and do something based on that.  Unfortunately, there is no simple way to determine how many items are in a menu when extending the `WP_Nav_Walker` class.

Answer (score 1):

Count the level 0 elements in a static variable in the method and add an extra class if you hit the third. Sample code:

```
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    static $column = 1;
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    if ($depth > 0)
    {
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='subsubmenu'>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $column += 1;
        $extra = 3 === $column ? ' third-column' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='submenu$extra'>\n";
    }
}
```